# Converting bytes read from a file using numpy fromfile to unicode in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to read a string of bytes from a file using NumPy `fromfile` in Python 3. My goal is to convert the bytes to a normal Python 3 string. For example:

```
$ echo "1234" > t.txt
```

Now the file `t.txt` contains 4 bytes of text. Then:

```
import numpy as np

values=np.fromfile('t.txt',dtype='|S1',count=4)
print ("values={}".format(values))
values=np.fromfile('t.txt',dtype='|U1',count=4)
print ("values={}".format(values))
```

gives:

```
values=[b'1' b'2' b'3' b'4']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./t.py", line 12, in <module>
    print ("values={}".format(values))
  File "/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 1715, in array_str
    return array2string(a, max_line_width, precision, suppress_small, ' ', "", str)
  File "/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/arrayprint.py", line 454, in array2string
    separator, prefix, formatter=formatter)
  File "/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/arrayprint.py", line 328, in _array2string
    _summaryEdgeItems, summary_insert)[:-1]
  File "/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/arrayprint.py", line 500, in _formatArray
    word = format_function(a[-1])
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-32-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-3: codepoint not in range(0x110000)
```

I would like to obtain a normal Python 3 string like `values='1234'`. How can this be done?

Comment: what if you use `dtype='|S4'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `astype` to convert the bytes to str:

```
import numpy as np

values = np.fromfile('t.txt',dtype='|S1',count=4).astype('|U1')
print(values)
# ['1' '2' '3' '4']

print(values.view('|U4'))
# ['1234']

print(values.dtype)
# <U1
```

Comment: Here is an alternative: `np.fromfile('t.txt',dtype='int8',count=4).tostring().decode()`

Answer (score 1):

I know the question explicitly asks for `np.fromfile`, but why not simply use the built-in file interface directly?

```
f = open('t.txt', 'r')
values = f.read().rstrip('\n')
f.close()
```

Note: Python 3 strings are Unicode by default.